# How do I print progress of a single cell to the console using papermill?

Tags: python-3.x, papermill

I want my program to print the progress to the console as it is running using papermill. I'm using the following code:

```
print(str(int(float(percentage)*100))
```

In a `for` loop and it doesn't print the string to the console so I have no idea as to how far along the progress is other than watching the `stage` part of the output in papermill. The papermill code goes as follows:

```
/your/dir/>papermill "yournotebook.ipynb" "your notebook output.ipynb"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used:

> --progress-bar

Example:

```
/your/dir/>papermill "yournotebook.ipynb" "your notebook output.ipynb" --log-output --log-level DEBUG --progress-bar
```